# Порядок присваивания в пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Я никак не могу найти в интернете этот вопрос, поэтому пишу сюда. Задача такая: написать алгоритм сортировки пузырьком, записывая каждый шаг в массив и вывести историю изменений в консоль.

У меня в консоль выводится только самое последнее изменение несколько раз. Почему так происходит? Как мне исправить эту ошибку, чтоб выводилась вся история?

```
def bubble_sort(colors):                                                                                      
    # Сюда записываем историю сортировки и исходные значения                                                  
    history = []                                                                                              
    history.append(colors)                                                                                    
    # Сортировка пузырьком                                                                                    
    for i in range(len(colors) - 1):                                                                          
        for j in range(len(colors) - 1):                                                                      
            if colors[j] < colors[j + 1]:                                                                     
                # Обмен значений                                                                              
                colors[j], colors[j + 1] = colors[j + 1], colors[j]                                           
            history.append(colors)                                                                            

    return history                                                                                            

def main():                                                                                                   

    colors = [0x33, 0x23, 0x22, 0x44, 0xFF]                                                                   
    result = bubble_sort(colors)                                                                              
    # Вывод на экран всей истории                                                                             
    for i in range(len(result)):                                                                              
        print(result[i])                                                                                      

main()
```

Comment: в конце print(reult[i]) -- забыл поправить

Comment: Так у вас неверно реализован пузырек. j  должен быть от n-1до i

Comment: как и отметил  `becouse`, вы добавляете в список одно и тоже, с каждым кругом..

Comment: даже если и неправильно написал, то почему в истории не сохраняются первоначальные значения?

Comment: @finally нет, не одно и тоже. В смысле, одно и то же, но не то одно и то же, о котором может подумать автор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему так происходит: в `history` добавляются не значения списка `colors`, а ссылка на сам список. По сути там хранится одно и тоже несколько раз. Это можно увидеть, выводя на экран `history` в каждой итерации.

Как исправить: заменить

```
history.append(colors)
```

на

```
history.append(colors.copy())
```

PS. Вместо

```
for i in range(len(result)):                                                                              
    print(result[i])
```

в питоне используется

```
for i in result:                                                                              
    print(i)
```

И старайтесь не давать переменным имена из одной буквы. Даже `num` или `index` намного понятней, чем просто `i`.

Comment: сложно придумать названия в таких вложенных циклах, если i это index, то j как обозвать? или ваще избежать вложенных циклов?

Comment: @ВиталийДавыдов лучше избегать, но вообще i,j - дефолтные переменные.. а вообще,как и сказано в ответе, имена в таких случаях исходят из того, по чему идет итерация, например, если это список `numbers`, то будет `for number in numbers`